# Swift 2.0 'unexpected trailing closure' error with lazy var assignment

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm converting a project to Swift 2.0 and I keep coming across this error everywhere that I'm using a lazy var. This code works perfectly in 1.2 but breaks in 2.0:

```
lazy private var placeholderImage = UIImage(named: "theImage")
```

But, this code generates an 'unexpected trailing closure' error in 2.0.

Following the Xcode's suggestions to fix the error, this is what I come out with:

```
lazy private var placeholderImage: UIImage = UIImage(named: "theImage")!
```

This compiles and seems to work, but I don't understand why the change was necessary in the first place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[In Apple developer forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/7437#22675) an Apple Staff (*ChrisLattner*) said:

> Yep, this is a known bug (and often reported) where type inference
>   isn't working properly with lazy properties.  Adding the explicit type
>   annotation is the best way to work around this for now.

the issue is also discussed in  [this Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/swift-language/dc6WeMtaFSw)

Comment: Thanks for the links!