# String literals in lazy vars in Swift 2 / XCode 7 [Cannot convert value of type String ...]

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7

Whenever a String literal appears in the declaration of a `lazy var` I get a compilation error in Swift 2 / XCode 7: `Cannot convert value of type String to expected argument type '(_builtinStringLiteral: RawPointer, byteSize: Word, isASCII: Int1)' ...`

(I had no problems in Swift 1.2 / XCode 6)

The simplest line that produces this error looks something like this:

```
lazy var foo = "bar"
```

But more relevantly (annoyingly), it also happens with initializers that take string arguments:

```
lazy var viewsLabel = HWLabel(color: COLOR_WHITE, font: ProximaNova("Semibold", 13))
lazy var durationIconView = HWIconView(imageName: "TimeIcon", color: COLOR_WHITE)
```

These are obviously my own initializers, and I'm noticing Apple SDKs don't seem to have Strings as args in initializers very often. Are Strings in `init`s bad practice?

<del>What does work is wrapping the declaration in a block.</del>

I might do that for now, or just make them not `lazy`.

I'm still curious though. Is this an XCode 7 bug?

***UPDATE:***

Just noticed that what does work is **not** wrapping the declaration in a closure, but rather specifying the type of the var so that it's not inferred.

So, **what does work**:

```
lazy var viewsLabel: HWLabel = HWLabel(color: COLOR_WHITE, font: ProximaNova("Semibold", 13))
lazy var durationIconView: HWIconView = HWIconView(imageName: "TimeIcon", color: COLOR_WHITE)
```

Why the appearance of a String in a `lazy var` declaration messes with type inference is beyond me. Still have a hunch it might be an XCode 7 bug.

Comment: It seems that an explicit type annotation helps, e.g. `lazy var foo : String = "bar"`.

Comment: Ha, thanks @MartinR! Just noticed that too and updated my question.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: I notice now I get a similar error when I don't add a type annotation on lazy vars that are "custom" classes (my own subclasses), e.g. `lazy var vc = MyViewController()` gives an error like "Cannot convert value of type 'UIViewController' to specified type 'MyViewController'"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bug, if you add the type of the var it could compile :

I found the answer here : [Swift 2.0 'unexpected trailing closure' error with lazy var assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31598187/swift-2-0-unexpected-trailing-closure-error-with-lazy-var-assignment)